# PSMultiValueSpecifier - iPhone SDK + Settings Bundle

Tags: iphone, settings-bundle

I want to use the PSMultiValueSpecifier in the settings bundle for my iphone app, but for some reason it doesn't want to work?

Does anyone know a good tutorial or sample code on how to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have all 6 Values entered for it:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSMultiValueSpecifier.html

For each Values entry, it should have a Titles Entry corresponding to it.

Comment: Hmmm
I did, for some reason it doesn't work? Do you have iChat or possibly you could send me a sample .plist ?

Answer (score 1):

The following works, if the PSMultiValueSpecifier is on the top / root level:

```
NSString *urlFromSettings = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"feed"];
```

I'm on my way to figure out, why it does not work, when used in a child pane.